# Figure out what PC settings are blocking me from upgrading to Windows 10 build 2004

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v2004

I used the windows 10 upgrade assistant to install windows 10 build 2004. I am getting this error:

> Your PC settings aren't supported yet on this version of Windows 10. Microsoft is working to support your settings soon. No action is needed. Windows Update will offer this version of Windows 10 automatically when these settings are supported

Is there a way to get the upgrader to tell me what condition it hit when it decided that computer is not eliglble? A log file somewhere? I am fine changing it, I just don't know what the problem is.

Here is the [scanresult.log](https://ghostbin.co/paste/a3xnc), the [scanresult.xml](https://pastebin.com/raw/SdbmCWZz) mentioned in that log, and the [BlueBox.log](https://ghostbin.co/paste/fhbux), [CompatData_2020_06_28_15_27_24_3_006f0018.xml](https://ghostbin.co/paste/sng32) (requested in the comments), and finally my [CBS.log](https://ghostbin.co/paste/x9zgn) file. `C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther\miglog.xml` and `C:\Windows\setupapi.log` do not exist on my computer.

Comment: [There are several know issues with 2004.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-2004) When those conditions are detected Microsoft blocks 2004 on those machines.  You should absolutely not attempt a manual upgrade to 2004.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand, but I want to know what condition I'm hitting to see if it's something fixable. For example, if it's something I disabled using O&O ShutUp10, I could re-enable the setting. If it's an issue with my RAM, I could buy a different type of RAM that doesn't have the problem. I'm willing to fix the issue, I just need to know what it is.

Comment: O&O ShutUp 10 absolutely would be the culprit.  I linked to the know issues, those issues indicate if it will block the upgrade, if and only if none of those issues are applicable can you feel safe to manually upgrade to 2004.  Unfortunately, without know what options you enabled or disabled by using O&O ShutUp 10 it will be next to impossible for us to determine which setting is to blame.  That program is know to make irreversible breaking changes to Windows 10 that causes all sorts of behavior.  That message wouldn’t be caused by a memory incompatibility only hardware on the known issues.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in my question - I'm asking if there's a way to get the upgrader to tell me what condition it hit when it decided that computer is not eliglble. I'm not looking for someone on this website to tell me, I understand that it would be difficult (or impossible) to tell me the specific issue with only the information I've given

Comment: [If your not looking for an answer I cannot really help.](https://superuser.com/questions/1451874/windows-2019-update-says-device-isnt-quite-ready-for-it-what-exactly-do-the/1451877#1451877).  I will again point out, it’s more likely a hardware block, if you upgrade to 2004 instead of simply waiting you will regret it.  The logs for the upgrade assistance will actually indicate the reason.  If you provide those logs to the community someone can tell you the reason your getting that message.  This will be my last comment on the subject without those logs.

Comment: The answer I'm looking for would be the location of a log file or something similar that contains the answer I need. I'm willing to buy hardware that doesn't have the problem but I don't want to read through all the known issues to figure out which piece of hardware I have is the blocker.

Comment: BitLocker absolutely isn’t the reason for the hardware block.

Comment: I don't have bitlocker enabled, but thank you. Where are the logs? That is the answer I'm looking for

Comment: [Logs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928901/log-files-that-are-created-when-you-upgrade-to-a-new-version-of-window).  Please provide the necessary information to answer your question.  Simply telling you where the logs are isn’t an acceptable answer.  You might not be looking to be told the reason for the block but that is indeed the only acceptable answer (IMO)

Comment: Okay, I can add the log files. Do you want all four listed under `The following log files are created when an upgrade fails during installation before the computer restarts for the second time:`? Or are there additional logs that would help as well

Comment: [Setup Diag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-logs) in the past has also told me the reason a feature update failed to install.  You should provide the relevant information from the logs.

Comment: I included the first logs. The CBS.log file is large enough that I'm having trouble finding a place to upload it to, but I'll add it in the next 20-30 minutes when I can find a place that will take it

Comment: **Sources\Panther\CompatData_2020_06_28_15_27_24_3_006f0018.xml** might contain a device identification number.  You definitely have incompatible hardware.  Your best solution is to simply wait for the block to be moved.  Do you have any of the drivers Microsoft has indicated on your system?

Comment: [Here is that file](https://ghostbin.co/paste/sng32) (also added to the question). I need this update for a feature in WSL2 (a build pipeline I use is broken on WSL classic), I am willing to replace the blocking hardware. Which log contains the drivers you are referring to? I will check.

Comment: I read through the file and I think the problems are laid out on lines 21 and 22. `oem1.inf` and `oem2.inf` have a value of "True" for BlockMigration. Is there a way to map that to a driver? I opened the file and it looks like an XPS Document Writer, but I don't have enough experience with drivers to know what that refers to.

Comment: You might not be able to replace the hardware.  There is at least one hardware block that is soldered to your motherboard.  Do you have any of those system files on your system?  The logs don’t indicate the precise hardware just that it’s detected during the first phase (before or around 50%) in other words it’s not even getting to the phase where it attempts the installation.  What are the contents of those two .inf files?

Comment: Location of [oem1.inf and oem0.inf](https://www.howtogeek.com/416169/how-to-fix-what-needs-your-attention-windows-10-setup-errors/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109986/discussion-between-ramhound-and-jon).

Comment: @Ramhound this discussion got me far enough of the way to figure out what was blocking me, I think you could post an answer with the location of the logs, how to read them, and possible solutions (for example the oemX.inf locations and how to check what devices/drivers they are for). MS Print to PDF driver was blocking me so I disabled it in windows features and that let me go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

### To disable Core Isolation?

1. Update your hardware drivers
2. Disable Core Isolation by going to Settings > Windows Security > Open Windows Security > Devie Security > Core isolation details.
3. Keep checking Windows 10 2004 release information page for mitigations and resolutions for Known issues.

### Updating offline

Download the update, disable internet, apply the update, enabled internet back after the update is applied.

[ref.](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-2004-upgrades-blocked-by-useless-what-needs-your-attention-alerts/)